# How to map ids in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Truck and Crew models, Truck `has_many :crews`. On frontend-side in checkboxes I select truck ids and send them to my controller. I need to destroy only trucks which have no crews. What I have now:

```
# app/models/truck.rb
belongs_to :company
has_many :crews

# app/models/crew.rb
belongs_to :truck, optional: true

# trucks_controller.rb
def bulk_destroy
  trucks_with_crews = []
  current_company.trucks.where(id: params[:ids]).find_each do |truck|
    if truck.crews.exists?
      trucks_with_crews << truck
      next
    end
    truck.destroy
  end
  if trucks_with_crews.empty?
    head :no_content
  else
    message = []
    trucks_with_crews.each_with_object([]) { |x| message << x.name }
    render json: { message: "Trucks: '#{message.join(', ')}' can't be deleted because used by crews." }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

But it's very overcomplicated, and I want to make it better in the query. Anyone can help me?

I think it should be something like:

- select ids of all who cannot be deleted (of course from those whose
  ids came to us)
- subtract them from the general list of incoming ids
- delete remaining in the general list

I don't know exactly how to do it:

```
a = current_company.trucks.where(id: params[:ids])
b = current_company.trucks.includes(:crews).where(truck.crews.map(&:id))
a = a - b
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please clarify. If somebody want to delete truck1 and truck2 (truck1 has no crews, truck2 has some crews), should he receive an error or should only truck1 be deleted?

Comment: Btw, maybe you should display only trucks without crews on frontend for deletion?

Comment: Only truck1,  json message with trucks who can't delete its not important now, just a simple msg what a someone cannot be delete :)

Comment: Не, просто отображать не получится) Нужно именно из приходящего array с ids находить каждого у кого по id есть crew, их не удалять, а тех кто без крю тех удалять)

Comment: Let speak in English since we are on English SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you can add a restriction to Truck model to not delete accidentally a truck with crew

```
has_many :crews, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
```

Let's refactor your controller code:

```
def bulk_destroy      
  # let find truck which should be deleted
  trucks_wo_crew = current_company.trucks.includes(:crews)
    .where(id: params[:ids]).where(crews: { id: nil })
  # and delete them
  trucks_wo_crew.destroy_all

  # if we search by id after deletion we'll get trucks with crew, 
  # because we already deleted other. 
  # We can get only names, since we don't need other info
  trucks_with_crew = current_company.trucks.where(id: params[:ids]).pluck(:name)

  return head :no_content if trucks_with_crew.empty?

  render json: { message: "Trucks: '#{trucks_with_crew.join(', ')}' can't be deleted because used by crews." }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Comment: Thx very much :)